# SQL Server error 5105 cannot bring db online

Tags: sql-server

I took a database offline to make read/write, but now I can't bring it back online. I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Probably a silly question but is the E:\ accessible from the server? and is path \SQL Databases\ valid?  (Did you somehow lose the E:\ mapping) did someone switch the path on you while it was down?   or is E:\ local?

Comment: e is accessible. other dbs reside in that directory and run.

Comment: Are the files themselves set to be read/write?  Did an attribute change?

Comment: Or perhaps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836873/en-us

Comment: Is it possible another process prevent SQL from takin ownership of the file? For instance an antivirus?